# Why doesn't my click function work in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wan to create a simple carousel that holds an image title and text. When I click the "next" span, it should display the next two `<li>`. But nothing happens when I do so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#right').click(function() {
            $('li').animate({
                left: '-600px'
            }, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFxcq/)

See [this example](http://andres321r.byethost15.com/carousel/).

Comment: GET http://andres321r.byethost15.com/carousel/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you recreate your problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: @RUJordan That is irrelevant, it's the jquery map so you can decompress the code and get the variable names instead of a,b,c...

Comment: You don't need the jQuery mapping file for it to work. Plus, that error appears only when you have the dev tools open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pure CSS issue. You need only to add `position: relative;` to your `li`, so you can effect the `left` property in your script.

```
.carousel-inner li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative; // Add this so setting a left position will work
}
```

Simply try adding that in Chrome Inspector and you'll see it works. Ciao!

Comment: Yes that worked! Thanks, Now I would need to read more into how to make it a functional carousel lol.

Comment: Happy to help. Additionally, there is always the jQuery Cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/. Also, I have a small Github example of a cycler function that might help you: https://github.com/kunalbhat/cycler

Comment: Yeah I know there's a lot of plugins out there but I want to start learning how to create my own lol. I'll have a look at yours to see if I learn anything. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to your **.carousel-inner li**.